# Setting tabBarItem.badgeValue in other classes?

Tags: iphone

I seem to have a problem with my tabBar items. Doing the creation of the tabBar I'm able to set this property of the tabBarItem that I want like so:

```
viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

    UIViewController *viewController3 = [[ThirdViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];


    UIViewController *viewController4 = [[FourthViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FourthViewController" bundle:nil];

    //Create our NavigationViewController object
    NavigationViewController *navController = [[NavigationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NavigationViewController" bundle:nil];

    //Create our UINavigationController
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:navController];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[nav, viewController2, viewController4, viewController3];

    nav.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]
                      initWithTitle:(@"Menukort")
                      image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"162-receipt.png"]
                      tag:0];

    viewController2.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:(@"Favoritter")
                                  image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"28-star.png"]
                                  tag:1];

    viewController3.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:(@"Info")
                                  image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"104-index-cards.png"]
                                  tag:2];

    viewController4.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:(@"Kort")
                                  image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"103-map.png"]
                                  tag:3];

    viewController2.tabBarItem.badgeValue = @"1";    

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

All this code is within a singleton, so sharing objects shouldn't be a problem. Now - how would I set the badgeValue of this tabBarItem in another class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your view controller class use     self.tabBarController.tabBarItem.badgeValue = @"<Any Value>". You can do it in viewdidLoad method

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. Nothing happens to the visuals.

Comment: R u using a UINavigationController? Infact you are,So use     [[self.navigationController tabBarItem] setBadgeValue:@""]

Comment: That's a step in the right direction - I'm getting the badge to show - it's just happening to the wrong tabbaritem. Problem is that It's getting set to the first tabbaritem. I want it to set the badge of the second tabbaritem. I also need to set this badge from the view itself - that is the second tabbaritem :)

Thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself in another thread.

I did it like this:

```
[[[[[self tabBarController] tabBar] items] 
                   objectAtIndex:tabIndex] setBadgeValue:badgeValueString];
```

Answer (score 0):

Get array of tabbarController's viewController using

`NSArray *arr = [self.tabbarController viewController];`

Then set value for any view controller using

```
[[[arr objectIndex:1] tabBarItem] setbadgeValue:<nsinteger some value>];
```

Comment: Defining the array I get the following message: No visible @interface for 'UITabBarController' declares the selector 'viewController'. What to do? :)